# IdentityServer 4 and identity by xml in request

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

We are developing a new B2B solution that consist of website and some number of web API and we want to use IdentityServer 4 as an authentication part of new solution.

In previous version of solution there was special authentication flow for one of customers:

1. With the request a customer user passed XML in a header.
2. This XML was checked for signature and source (ip address).
3. Base on this XML user was authenticated in system.

Is it possible to do same flow with IdentityServer 4 in parallel with usual login/password? If yes, what should be the proper way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html

Comment: @leastprivilege Thanks for your help. Maybe I did not understood correct documentation, but I want to check XML and IP before giving a token to a user. Validity of XML should be a reason to give a token. Same as checking login/password for give a token. 
Is there any way to do it properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes - it is called an extension grant in OAuth2 - the link points to how to implement something like that in IdentityServer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Was confused with confused with checking the token to give a token.